# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'into', problem when try to create a view?

Tags: sql-server

This problem is when I try to create a view inside of one .dbo.
After I remove into statement, it showed me another error same as before just near the keyword FROM.

```
WITH temptable(strict,DataItem, description) AS
(
    SELECT
        strict,
        CAST(LEFT(description, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), description + CHAR(10)) - 1) AS nvarchar(50)),
        CAST(STUFF(description, 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), description + CHAR(10)), '') AS nvarchar(50))
    from safezone where id= 12
    UNION all

    SELECT
        strict,
        CAST(LEFT(description, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), description + CHAR(10)) - 1) AS nvarchar(50)),
        CAST(STUFF(description, 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), description + CHAR(10)), '') AS nvarchar(50))
    FROM temptable
    WHERE
        description > ''
        
)


SELECT
    strict,
    DataItem
into info FROM temptable
ORDER BY strict
option (maxrecursion 0)

SELECT replace(info.DataItem,'  ',' ')as predmet, info.strict,po.yearwriteoff,po.position
from info 
left join safezone on info.strict=safezone.strict
order by strict
```

How can I fix this

Comment: A `VIEW` can't perform `DDL` and `DML` statements; it's simply a virtual table defined by a `SELECT`. You can't use a clause like `INTO` in a `VIEW`'s definition.

Comment: So how can i perform this without clause like INTO?

Comment: WEll, you have 2 statements there, so you'd need 2 views. And the first view cannot have an the `INTO`, `ORDER BY`, or `OPTION` clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot insert records in a view, but it looks like you just want to temporarily store the first result set for your last query. You *can* use multiple common table expressions (CTE) and each CTE can use all previous CTE's.

Try this:

```
-- first CTE definition
WITH temptable(strict,DataItem, description) AS
(
    SELECT
        strict,
        CAST(LEFT(description, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), description + CHAR(10)) - 1) AS nvarchar(50)),
        CAST(STUFF(description, 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), description + CHAR(10)), '') AS nvarchar(50))
    from safezone where id= 12
    UNION all

    SELECT
        strict,
        CAST(LEFT(description, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), description + CHAR(10)) - 1) AS nvarchar(50)),
        CAST(STUFF(description, 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), description + CHAR(10)), '') AS nvarchar(50))
    FROM temptable
    WHERE
        description > ''
        
),
-- second CTE definition
info(strict, DataItem) as
(
    SELECT
        strict,
        DataItem
    FROM temptable
)
-- final selection
SELECT replace(info.DataItem,'  ',' ')as predmet, info.strict,po.yearwriteoff,po.position
from info 
left join safezone on info.strict=safezone.strict
order by strict
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Remark: the second CTE has no added value here. Just for demonstration purposes. You can just use `temptable` (with alias `info`?) instead of `info` in the last selection.

Comment: Again, same error (Error in SELECT clause: expression near 'INTO'.
Unable to parse query text.)

Comment: Cleaned up answer. I cannot validate your query on my machine, because you did not provide a full [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The query still is not valid, there is no `po` table alias, but there isn't one in your query either...